# Why does this XQuery query not find any nodes for the keyword?

Tags: java, xml, xquery

I want to write an XQuery query that returns XML elements that have *any* XML element containing a keyword, say ***'countdown'***. I wrote following query and is not working:

```
for $entity in collection('data2.dbxml')//movie
where contains( $entity/ * , 'countdown' ) return $entity
```

Why, and how to write the correct query?

An example XML document is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movies  xmlns:xlink= " http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink " >
 <movie>
 <title> " 100 Jahre - Der Countdown "  (1999) {1998 - Der Präsident und das Mädchen (#10.8)}
 </title>
 <url>http://www.imdb.com/Title? " 100 Jahre - Der Countdown "  (1999) {1998 - Der Präsident und    
  das Mädchen (#10.8)}
 </url>
 <overview>
  <releasedates>
     <releasedate>Germany 30 December 1999 
     </releasedate>
  </releasedates>
  </overview>
  <cast>
  <actors>
     <actor>
        <name>Brückner Christian
        </name>
        <character>Narrator
        </character>
     </actor>
     <actor>
        <name>Clinton Bill (I)
        </name>
        <character>(archive footage)  Himself
        </character>
     </actor>
     <actor>
        <name>Lewinsky Monica
        </name>
        <character>(archive footage)  Herself
        </character>
     </actor>
  </actors>
 </cast>
  <additional_details>
  </additional_details>
  <fun_stuff>
 </fun_stuff>
 </movie>
</movies>
```

Comment: Example data would be very useful for testing / solving this issue.

Comment: For a good question, please always add current and expected output, and describe _exactly_ why your code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

XQuery is case sensitive, "Countdown" and "countdown" are not the same. Furthermore, `contains($string, $needle)` expects a single string, and not a sequence. Luckily, XQuery implicitly casts any element including its subtree to a string by concatenating all text nodes.

```
for $movie in collection('data2.dbxml')//movie
where contains(lower-case($movie), 'countdown')
return $movie
```

Comment: Hi Jens, I want to use wildcard for ANY ELEMENT. If wildcard is suported. This is because different elements have different level in the document

Comment: The code above checks all movies whether _any_ element inside the movie contains the text 'countdown'. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to use XQuery full text for this because it will take are of case sensitivity, etc:

```
for $entity in collection('data2.dbxml')//movie
  where $entity contains text 'countdown'
return $entity
```

If you don't have access to it then use the answer Jens provided.

Comment: Thank Ewout. The suggestion from Jens work. Yours gave the fowolling error

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected <qualified name>, expecting return [err:XPST0003], <query>:1:71,

Comment: most likely the XQuery processor you're using doesn't support the XQuery Full Text spec